Can I plagiarize from my own patent that was drafted by an attorney?
An attorney has drafted a patent for me. While most of the content of the patent are written by me and then revised by the attorney, the attorney has also injected the required boilerplate statements and one drawing.
I am about to draft a second patent by myself.
Is it OK for me to plagiarize the attorney's boilerplate statements and the one drawing?

Is this a copyright question?

I am not sure...

You might ask the attorney but I think you will not get in trouble. Not an answer.

The text of the application might well be considered your property considering you paid the lawyer. This would be better asked on the Law SE site.
